# Scikit-Learn's `_openmp_effective_n_threads()` returns 1, causing HistGradientBoostingRegressor to run on only 1 core

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, cpu

the title pretty much says it all. I am troubleshooting why sklearn model is only running on 1 cpu core, when usually it will run on as many cores as I have available. I found behind the scenes it is setting the `n_threads` attribute with this convenience method from Scikit-Learn: `_openmp_effective_n_threads` ([source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/897c0c570511be4b7912a335052ed479ac5ca1f3/sklearn/utils/_openmp_helpers.pyx#L21)).

So I fired up a fresh python kernel in my desired environment and I call this function and find it returns 1. This is what is limiting my program. Why is this function returning 1 here and is there something I can do to all this to see that I actually have many CPUs available?

Just seeing this comment in the comments of the source code:

> If scikit-learn is built without OpenMP support, always return 1.

Here is a better example of the symptoms:

```
Python 3.12.0 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Oct  2 2023, 17:29:18) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.utils._openmp_helpers import _openmp_effective_n_threads, _openmp_parallelism_enabled
>>> _openmp_parallelism_enabled()
False
```

I feel like there is a version mismatch somewhere because I am installing a custom fork of Scikit-Learn that I have not been keeping up to date. On another computer I have it working with Python version 3.8, but I tried to install this version of sklearn in a new computer, and it always seems to have this problem of no parallel support.

I think my question comes down to this command: `_openmp_parallelism_enabled()`. I need to figure out why this is returning false.

Thanks.

Comment: What system are you running it on?  Linux, Windows, Mac, FreeBSD, Solaris, what?  In a VM?  If Linux, how many cores are in `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. This is a linux system. I use anaconda primarily to set up virtual environments for python dev. This is indeed a Ryzen 9 with 16 cores as shown in cpuinfo.